# How to define a callable function whenever the value of any element in the list gets changed?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I know this question is kind of simple and silly but I got stymied of searching the internet. Consider we have a 2-dimensional list in Python which represents a game board of hex and its elements would be changed by some function (like playing stone at some cell in the game board).

What I am looking for is a tool in Python that could define a function to be called whenever the value of any element in the array gets changed.
I already found the function `trace` in tkinter which calls a function when `StringVar`,`DoubleVar` and so on get changed.

I was wondering if a similar one could be found for simple lists or even numpy lists.

Comment: Create your custom list (a class inheriting from `list`) and overwrite `__setitem__` method. Also have a look at event managers.

Comment: `Numpy` array doesn't have such a functionality. You can implement your custom object by inherit from `numpy.array` class. You can start here http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.subclassing.html

Comment: Do you know that when you modify the list as in `lst[i] = val` you could change the code to: `lst[i]  =val; callaback(lst, i)` and be done?  To avoid code duplicate just use a function to set the items: `def set_item(lst, i): lst[i]=val;callaback(lst, i)`.  Sure you can avoid this by inheritance, but inheriting built-ins and `numpy` arrays is much less trivial than it sounds, and *a lot* more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements:

- 2-dimensinal list in python which represents a game board of hex
- and its elements would be changed by some function (like playing stone at some cell in the game board).
- a function to be called whenever the value of any element in the array gets changed.

The straight forward way to implement this is to define a class representing the `board` and actions.  It will contain the 2d list (could be `numpy` array, but that may not be necessary).

It would also define methods that change the list, and perform the recording/callback.

```
class Board():
    def __init__(...)
        self.list2d=[]   # 2d nested list
    def record_play(...):
        <action when a cell is changed>
    def play(...):
        <change self.list2d>
        self.record_play(...)
```

As long a the `Board` object controls all the changes, you don't need a more generic tracking tool, or even a subclass of list or array (though those are possible).  Just make sure you call the tracking function each time you call the change function.

If you were doing this across different classes and kinds of objects it could be worth while constructing something more abstract. But for a one-off case, just do the obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. if you could put some actual code which could be executed, that would be highly appreciated. I would learn much faster